# GetStream.ClientError.jsonDecode Error on fetching the activity in getStream

Tags: json, swift, codable, getstream-io

When I m trying to fetch the activity for a perticualar ID i m getting the response but parsing is getting failed. Problem is parsing is getting failed in a class defined in GetStream Pod. (class is EnrichedActivity)

Below is the request

```
Client.shared.get(typeOf: Activity.self, activityIds: ["76ec29ef-9346-11e9-85a5-0a539f6bda0a"], completion: { (result) in

})
```

And json response is :

```
{
"duration": "0.83ms",
"results": [{
    "actor": "SU:commentRefresh",
    "foreign_id": "",
    "id": "76ec29ef-9346-11e9-85a5-0a539f6bda0a",
    "object": "Hello",
    "origin": null,
    "target": "",
    "time": "2019-06-20T10:30:46.369330",
    "verb": "post"
}]
}
```

But parsing is getting failed , Error is :

> GetStream.ClientError.jsonDecode("The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.", Optional(Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "actor", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil)))

Below is the Activity Class :

```
public final class Activity: EnrichedActivity<User, ActivityObject, Reaction>, TextRepresentable, AttachmentRepresentable {

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case text
    case attachments
}

public var text: String?
public var attachment: ActivityAttachment?
var showReactionView = false

public var original: Activity {
    switch object {
    case .repost(let activity):
        return activity
    default:
        return self
    }
}

public init(actor: User, verb: Verb, object: ActivityObject, feedIds: FeedIds? = nil) {
    super.init(actor: actor, verb: verb, object: object, feedIds: feedIds)
}

required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    text = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .text)
    attachment = try container.decodeIfPresent(ActivityAttachment.self, forKey: .attachments)
    print("parsing EnrichActivity")
   // print(try? super.init(from: decoder))
    try super.init(from: decoder)
    print("parsing of super got complete")
}

override public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(text, forKey: .text)
    try container.encodeIfPresent(attachment, forKey: .attachments)
    try super.encode(to: encoder)
}
```

}

Comment: Hey Aashish, could you show the code of your `Activity` type?

Comment: I m using the same class given at stream demo code. Link is: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-swift

Comment: Even in there demo code not working.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug with enrichment for getting activities by ids. The fix will be today or tomorrow.

Comment: thanks for the update. I investigated more. Problem is the with actor. In response actor is coming as string while it should come as [String:Any](full user data) like it come when we fetch all activities.

Comment: Yes, and to fix that the request should be with enrich parameter, then the server will return a User json object for actor.

Comment: Hi Aashish. Please check the new version 1.2.0